# Flex Release build not including all files and folders in the exported release

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, release-builds

I'm trying to export a release build of a project that includes folders for assets, VO, controllers, models, and view. When I export a release build, the release build is not including all the files and folders that are in the project root in flex builder. It only includes the main flex application files as well as the assets and controllers folder. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by reinstalling my install of Flash Builder and building a new project to migrate my original project in question into.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the controlles, VOs etc are used (referenced) in your project. In this case they will be compiled anyway. Everything that is refernced in your code will be compiled automatically.

You only need to explicitly include some folders if you have some assets in them that are loaded on runtime. In this case you can do it in the project settings (Right click on your project > Properites > Flex Build compiling > Package contents)